# Something (which might be called multi-continued fraction) for the A112487

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A112487](https://oeis.org/A112487) i.e. an integer sequence with exponential generating function
  $$
  A(x)=\exp\left(\int (A(x)+A(x)^2)\,dx\right), \\
  A(0)=1
  $$
  However, the definition in the name of the sequence is
  $$
  a(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}E_2(n,k)2^k
  $$
  where $E_2(n,k)$ is [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556), the second-order Eulerian numbers with the following recurrence:
  $$
  E_2(n, k) = kE_2(n-1, k) + (2n-k)E_2(n-1, k-1), \\
  E_2(0,0) = 1
  $$
- Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence with generating function $\frac{1}{G(0)}$ where
  $$
  G(j)=\cfrac{1-\cfrac{(j+1)x}{G(j+1)}}{1+\cfrac{(j+1)x}{G(j+1)}}
  $$
  Here $G(0)$ is something which might be called multi-continued fraction.

I conjecture that $$a(n)=b(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a(n)=local(A=1+x); for(i=1, n, A=exp(intformal(A+A^2)+x*O(x^n))); n!*polcoeff(A, n)
b(n)=local(CF=1+x*O(x)); for(j=0, n, CF=(1 - (n-j+1)*x/CF)/(1 + (n-j+1)*x/CF)); polcoeff(1/CF, n, x);
test(n)=a(n)==b(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Definition of $b(n)$ is unclear, no initial condition for the recurrence for $G$ is given.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, thank you for comment! $G(0)$ is completely defined by a given recurrence. Just put $j=0$ and then expand $G(1)$ using $G(2)$, then expand $G(2)$ using $G(3)$ and so on.

Comment: That expansion gives an expression of the form $G(j) = \frac{G(j+k)p_k(j,x) + q_k(j,x)}{G(j+k)r_k(j,x) + s_k(j,x)}$ where $p_k, r_k$ have constant coefficient $1$ and $q_k, s_k$ have constant coefficient $0$. How do you ever extract the linear coefficient of $G(0)$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! See PARI prog. By the way, if you try to reduce $G(j+1)$, it does not give a result.

Comment: Let $F(j)=-\frac{1}{G(j)}$, then $F(j)=1-\frac{2}{1+(j+1)x F(j+1)}$ and $(b_n)_{n\ge 0}$ has the generating function $-F(0)$.

Comment: @Notamathematician Let's check: $$F(j)=-\frac{1}{G(j)}=\frac{-1-\frac{(j+1)x}{G(j+1)}}{1-\frac{(j+1)x}{G(j+1)}}=\frac{-1+(j+1)xF(j+1)}{1+(j+1)xF(j+1)}=1-\frac{2}{1+(j+1)xF(j+1)}$$ and $(b_n)$ has generating function $\frac{1}{G(0)}=-F(0)$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein, sorry, I calculated incorrectly. You are absolutely right.